# How can I zoom past level 21 in Google Maps Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps-flutter

My application needs to show very fine zoom levels, maybe up to 26 or 27. I tried to set `mapType = MapType.none`, include my overlay, and set `minMaxZoomPreference: const MinMaxZoomPreference(0, 30)` on my GoogleMap object, but the zoom is still limited to level 21.

How can I make maps zoom to level 27 in Google Maps Flutter?